# Models with SLE scaling limit

Tags: lattices, pr.probability

What discrete processes/models have been proven to have scaling limits to $\text{SLE}(\kappa)$, for various $\kappa$?
I know about loop-erased random walk and uniform spanning trees.
What about conjectures in this direction? (Such as the double-dimer-cover cycles, which I read are conjectured to be $\text{SLE}(4)$)

I'm very new to this, so if you please could, together with the answer refer to a paper/article/survey accompanying the result, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you add the tag pr.probability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several other models proved to converge to SLE: critical percolation on the triangular lattice, Gaussian Free Field, Harmonic Explorer, and recently also the critical Ising model. You can check the paper Kevin linked or [Schramm's slides](http://dbwilson.com/schramm/memorial/ICM.pdf) from ICM2006 for some highlights. Just keep in mind that this is a fast changing field at the moment so there has been some progress since 2006.

Answer (score 7):

From Cardy's article http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503313

---

Some important special cases are therefore:

$\kappa = 2$: loop-erased random walks (proven in [24]);

$\kappa = 8/3$: self-avoiding walks, as already suggested by the restriction property, Sec. 3.5.2; 
unproven, but see [22] for many consequences;

$\kappa = 3$: cluster boundaries in the Ising model, however as yet unproven;

$\kappa = 4$: BCSOS model of roughening transition (equivalent to the 4-state Potts 
model and the double dimer model), as yet unproven; also certain level lines of a 
gaussian random ﬁeld and the ‘harmonic explorer’ (proven in [23]); also believed to 
be dual to the Kosterlitz-Thouless transition in the XY model;

$\kappa = 6$: cluster boundaries in percolation (proven in [7]);

$\kappa = 8$: dense phase of self-avoiding walks; boundaries of uniform spanning trees 
(proven in [24]).

It should be noted that no lattice candidates for κ > 8, or for the dual values κ < 2, have 
been proposed.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\kappa = 2$ for the LERW?

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples in this [readable survey article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602151v2) by Schramm.